# What's the stance on Overloading Tag Meanings

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

This edit was just approved: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5523868

[image: edit]

It seems like these are two entirely different things that happen to have the same name.  I think it would be better to have a separate tag like [hydra-web-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hydra-web-services) to disambiguate between the two, but couldn't find any authoritative resource to back that up.

Here are a couple meta posts that frown on having multiple meanings within a single tag:

- [The tag [using] on SO has overloaded meanings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40368/209031)
- [What's the best resolution to the overloaded “select” tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118270/209031)

---

It also looks like the [edit proposer has some affiliation with hyrda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25268414/1366033) that he is neither hiding nor fully disclosing

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125234/a-real-solution-to-ambiguous-tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not overload tags with different meanings.  If a given word/term has multiple meanings multiple different tags should be created to disambiguate those separate concepts such that each tag means just one thing.

In this specific case none of the questions using this tag refer to the concept described in this edit, so the edit is invalid.  If there are actual questions about that particular set of standards then a new and different tag that represents just that concept could be created to categorize those questions.

Answer (score 3):

Tags should only have one meaning.

If the same word could be used for two (or more) separate things then a new tag (like the one you suggest) should be created for the alternate meaning(s).

It may even be necessary to rename the tag for the original meaning. In this case create a further new tag and then create a synonym for the original and then ask a moderator to merge the tags so the new one is the master.