# Someone overloaded tag; how should we "unload"?

Tags: discussion, tags

I see from the [pgm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pgm) tag on SO, which has always been about the file format, the NetPBM Portable Gray Map, that someone has added *an extra meaning for "Pragmatic General Multicast"*:

> PGM is also an abbreviation for Pragmatic General Multicast

I also see from the the meta-question [What's the stance on Overloading Tag Meanings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268523/whats-the-stance-on-overloading-tag-meanings), that this kind of overloading is discouraged.

Now, what to do?

- Simply edit the tag back to its original, and delete anything about multicast + remove incorrect tags?
- Create a new tag for multicast, then retag + restore old tag text?
- As above, but also rename the original tag to disambiguate (this has some additional issues, because PGM is a part of a family of file formats, so one should probably also rename PBM, PPM and possibly PNM if it exists)?

*I see from the tag history that the edit is fairly old. But I think the issue should still be fixed though.*

Comment: Depends mostly on how many questions there are and whether they warrant own tags. But yes, +1, they should definitely be cleaned up!

Comment: Reading through, I was hoping somebody had added 'PGM is also an abbreviation of Precision Guided Munition', and we were now answering questions about a very different set of products. Sigh.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd say there'd ideally need to be two separate tags although any question tagged relating to Pragmatic General Multicast would need to be traced and have it's new tag added after removing the old.

The original tag could be edited to remove the overloaded description but also have its tag name edited to be more specific, e.g., netpbm-pgm.

I base this suggestion on the fact I mostly follow tags relating to Android and there are a lot of aspects such as a 'listview' which may be similar in different languages and on different platforms but might involve very different approaches. Consequently we have a tag for 'android-listview' as well as many others where there's a distinct difference in the use of different (similarly named) concepts.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. There's not that many questions that are tagged PGM, so I looked through them and retagged all network/multicast related questions "pgm-protocol" and moved the tag wiki for Pragmatic General Multicast there.