# Multiple meanings for [melt] tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

The summary for [melt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/melt) gives two different unrelated meanings for the tag:

> In R, the "melt" function...converts data into a long form. Melt is also a web application framework written in PHP.

According to [other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50218/218334) [meta-posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268523/1858225), it looks like such tags should be split into two tags. In the case of [melt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/melt), it looks like most questions have to do with `R`, but some questions aren't actually related to either of the meanings listed in the tag summary (for instance, there's one about Excel).

Looks like we need a clean-up.

(Sorry for not finding a good pun for my title.)

Comment: I have cleaned up some of the questions.  Very few were not about the R function.  Melt framework questions were added to the new [melt-framework] and questions about the `melt` command were merged into the [mlt] framework tag.  We still need to deal with the [python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/melt+python) questions.